# How to get each item's height into getItemLayout if the height is dynamic?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I want to use `getItemLayout` to let `<FlatList />` more efficient.

But when use `onLayout` to get my list height that is not stable, maybe 128 or 230 or 183.

So set `itemHeight` for 128 into `getItemLayout` is not working properly.

Is any other way to let my `itemHeight` get the dynamic height into my `getItemLayout`?

```
onLayout(event) {
  const {x, y, height, width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  console.log('height:', height); // the height is dynamic
}

renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View onLayout={(event) => this.onLayout(event)} style={styles.floorView} style={styles.itemView}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

<FlatList
  data={DUMMY_LIST}
  ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  numColumns={1}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  getItemLayout={(data, index)=> {
  return { length: itemHeight, offset: itemHeight * index , index };
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Someone posted this link: https://snack.expo.io/lqIdJSzD4 in another question like this one, however it didn't work in my app, maybe it would work in yours.